# Check for unique JSON keys in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server

In SQL Server, how can I check if a string is valid JSON and the keys are all unique?

According to the [T-SQL documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), the regular ISJSON method does not check that the keys on the same level are unique.

Comment: What version of SQL server?   2016 and up has nice, built-in JSON validation. Search for ISJSON, JSON_VALUE, JSON_QUERY

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Recursive Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to do this.  EG something like:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(4000) = N'{  
   "StringValue":"John",  
   "IntValue":45,  
   "TrueValue":true,  
   "FalseValue":false,  
   "NullValue":null,  
   "ArrayValue":["a","r","r","a","y"],  
   "ObjectValue":{"obj":"ect"}  
}';

with q as
(
  select [key] path, [key], value, type, 0 level
  from openjson(@json)
  union all
  select concat(q.path,'\',n.[key]), n.[key], n.value, n.type, q.level + 1
  from q 
  cross apply openjson(q.value) n
  where q.type in (4,5)
 )
 select *, count(*) over (partition by path) pathCount
 from q
```